# Substance 6.1 upgrade gives Substance delegate used when Substance is not the current LAF exception

Tags: java, look-and-feel, substance

I'm trying to upgrade my app to use the latest drop of substance L&F but the problem is that I got the Following exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Substance delegate used when Substance is not the current LAF [component JButton in window App under Substance Business Blue Steel]
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.SubstanceCoreUtilities.traceSubstanceApiUsage(SubstanceCoreUtilities.java:1972)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.SubstanceColorSchemeUtilities.getColorScheme(SubstanceColorSchemeUtilities.java:269)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.api.SubstanceLookAndFeel.getDisabledIcon(SubstanceLookAndFeel.java:2267)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.getDisabledIcon(AbstractButton.java:666)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaButtonUI.paintIcon(AquaButtonUI.java:356)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaButtonUI.paint(AquaButtonUI.java:295)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:153)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:34)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:60)
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:97)
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1793)
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3375)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paintComponent(RepaintArea.java:276)
    at sun.awt.RepaintArea.paint(RepaintArea.java:241)
    at apple.awt.ComponentModel.handleEvent(ComponentModel.java:263)
    at apple.awt.CWindow.handleEvent(CWindow.java:465)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4790)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:635)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Substance delegate used when Substance is not the current LAF [component JButton in window App under Substance Business Blue Steel]
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.SubstanceCoreUtilities.traceSubstanceApiUsage(SubstanceCoreUtilities.java:1972)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.internal.utils.SubstanceColorSchemeUtilities.getColorScheme(SubstanceColorSchemeUtilities.java:269)
    at org.pushingpixels.substance.api.SubstanceLookAndFeel.getDisabledIcon(SubstanceLookAndFeel.java:2267)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.getDisabledIcon(AbstractButton.java:666)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaButtonUI.paintIcon(AquaButtonUI.java:356)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaButtonUI.paint(AquaButtonUI.java:295)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:153)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:567)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:862)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5098)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4882)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:811)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:633)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

when I used the pervious version I don't have such error and I have set up the substance dependencies !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I'm setting the look and feel in the main thread and calling the GUI in a different thread.